# Should maximum likelihood estimate give same result as MLS for VAR model with time trend?

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

Question: For a VAR with a time trend, like (1), should the MLS estimator be the same as the maximum likelihood estimator?

A more lengthy discussion/statement of the question follows:

So I have been messing around with estimating the following Vector Autoregression in MatLab:

$$ \tag{1}
\begin{bmatrix}x_t \\y_t\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}p_1^1  & p_2^1 \\ p_1^2  &p_2^2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{t-1} \\ y_{t-1}\end{bmatrix} +
       \begin{bmatrix}g^x \\g^y\end{bmatrix}t + \begin{bmatrix}e_t^x \\e_t^y\end{bmatrix} $$

I can estimate this by doing OLS on the individual equations, which I did. I also did it by MLS and got the same result as OLS (which is expected since the equations have the same regressors).

However, when I try to do it using maximum likelihood, I obtain different estimates, which personally I think is because the estimates of $c_1$ and $c_2$ are very different then what I get from MLS. If I set $c_1$ and $c_2$ to the MLS estimates, than I get the correct estimates for $p_1^1$ $p_2^1 \dots$, **but I am wondering why MLS and maximum likelihood give me different results** (when I don't specify the constants before hand).

According [Wikipedia site on VAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression#Estimation) (and some books) "[The Multivariate Least Squares Estimator] is furthermore equal to the conditional maximum likelihood estimator". Their model does not include a time trend term, though.

Perhaps the difference I am seeing has do to with the fact that MLS equals the *conditional* maximum likelihood estimator? Or perhaps they are only asymptotically equal?

**So my question is this**: For a VAR with a time trend, like $(1)$, should the MLS estimator be the same as the maximum likelihood estimator?

I have not tried to derive the estimators mathematically and compare them, as I am not that vested in this question. If someone wants to derive them that is fine, but a simple yes/no with or without some intuition is fine.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps the conditioning is at fault. Otherwise I do not quite see why MLS and conditional maximum likelihood should differ.